# tr:hover not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to highlight (change background color) of the entire row when the mouse is hovering on a table row. I searched through the Net and it should be working, but it doesn't. I'm displaying it on Chrome.

```
<table class="list1">
<tr>
   <td>1</td><td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2</td><td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td><td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my css:

```
.list1 tr:hover{
background-color:#fefefe;
}
```

The correct css should be:

```
.list1 tr:hover td{
background-color:#fefefe;
}

//--this css for the td keeps overriding the one i showed earlier
.list1 td{
background-color:#ccc000;
}
```

Thanks for the feedback guys!

Comment: First I'd try cleaning up your markup - you're not closing all your td tags.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FnVhX/ its working

Comment: Well, the problem lies with the css. I did not show the full css here. In my code, the css for td was overriding the one for tr:hover. I just need to append 'td' behind .list1 tr:hover to achieve the effect.

Comment: That is because you have set `background-color` for `td`. In this situation the background of `td` covers the background of `tr`. so remove all `td` backgrounds then set all backgrounds for `tr`.

Answer (score 154):

Your best bet is to use

```
table.YourClass tr:hover td {
background-color: #FEFEFE;
}
```

Rows aren't fully support for background color but cells are, using the combination of :hover and the child element will yield the results you need.

Comment: Just to emphasize: all cells in a row will be highlighted as a result, not just the one you point to with a mouse.

Comment: Impressive answer!

Comment: I can't find any documentation on this syntax, what's the meaning of the top line? does it mean that if you hover over the 'tr', it will also apply the rule to the 'td'? is the prefix of the table.class relevant?

Comment: Nice answer. Was looking around a while and all I found were complicated javascript answers. This is great.

Comment: Hello from the future, Mr. Peters, I'm sure this will be an immortal answer, pure elegance, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` for :hover to work with anything other than the `<a>` tag. Try adding that to the top of your HTML.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
.list1 tr:hover td{
    background-color:#fefefe;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`tr:hover` doesn't work in old browsers.

You can use jQuery for this:

```css
.tr-hover
{  
  background-color:#fefefe;
}
```

```js
$('.list1 tr').hover(function()
{
    $(this).addClass('tr-hover');
},function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('tr-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me... The `tr:hover` should work. Probably it won't work because:

1. The background color you have set is very light. You don't happen to use this on a white background, do you?
2. Your `<td>` tags are not closed properly.

Please note that hovering a `<tr>` will not work in older browsers.

Comment: Correct. I was about to post the same thing. The background color is too light to see the difference on white and the td tags equilibrium is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Like @wesley says, you have not closed your first `<td>`. You opened it two times.

```html
<table class="list1">
<tr>
   <td>1</td><td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2</td><td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td><td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
.list1 tr:hover{
    background-color:#fefefe;
}
```

There is no JavaScript needed, just complete your HTML code

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `background` CSS property as follows:

```
tr:hover{
    background: #F1F1F2;    
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AwNc9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

**css code:**

```
.list1 tr:hover td {
    background-color:#fefefe;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try this`tr:hover td {color: aqua;}`
`

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important`:

```
.list1 tr:hover{
    background:#fefefe !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a similar problem, the problem was I was using background-color, use background: {anyColor}

example:

```
tr::hover td {background: red;}
```

This works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I found that if I use a DOCTYPE like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

it didn't work. But if I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```

it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it matters in which order the tags in your CSS file are styled. Make sure that your tr:nth-child and tr:hover td are described before table's td and th. Like so:

```
#tblServers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#tblServers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#tblServers tr:hover td{background-color: #c1c4c8;}

#tblServers td, #tblServers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#tblServers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4a536e;
  color: white;
}
```