# Javascript/Coffeescript mouse over function RoR

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a table that shows a list of jobs. What I would like to happen is for the text of the entire row (not td) to change color to red when it is hovered over and then back to black when the mouse is removed.

I currently have the following table:

```
<section id="table-wrapper">
    <table id="jobs">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>position</td>
                <td>company</td>
                <td>location</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
            <tr href='<%= job.job_url %>'>
                <td><%= job.title %></td>
                <td><%= job.company %></td> 
                <td><%= job.city %>, <%= job.country %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</section>
```

and despite my best efforts only have this so far in my coffeescript file:

```
$ ->
  $('tr[href]').mouseover -> $('tr td').css('color', 'red');
```

Currently this is turning all TD elements to red on hover regardless of the row they are in and they do not return to black when the mouse is removed.

Any advice people can offer either in Javascript or coffee script would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add mouseout event too!!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, have added mouseout event as well which has worked. Do you know how I can get it to only highlight the table row that is being hovered on rather than all td in the table? Sorry for the novice questions

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510811/834178) answer to another question.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use `<tr data-href="...">` instead of `<tr href="...">`, table rows don't have `href` attributes and you never know what a browser is going to do with invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this with CSS:

```
tr[href]:hover {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcel, I just tried this in simple CSS and can't seem to get it to work. Do you know the best way for me to isolate the row in Javascript because it's all working now other than it's highlighting all td's rather than just the row I need. thanks!

Comment: @TomPinchen: it just works for me using only this CSS rule, but if you really want to do this using JavaScript, just follow Paul Hoenecke's link.

Comment: Sorry I managed to get this working with table tr:hover {color:red} so all is good - thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `mouseover()`, use `hover()`. The `tr[href]:hover` selector will not perform great in css. Add .js-red-row to you `tr` as a non-styling css selector.

```
$ ->
  $('tr.js-red-row td').hover -> $(this).toggleClass('red')


# css    
tr > td {color: black;}
.red {color: red;}
```