# Hover highlight effect in a group of rows

Tags: jquery, css

I have quite a big table grouped by a `data` attribute which looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr data-group="666"><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-group="666"><td></td></tr>

    <tr data-group="2"><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-group="2"><td></td></tr>

    <tr data-group="XXXX"><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-group="XXXX"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I don't know in advance the value of the possible groups (could be more than 50 groups). They are generated dynamically.

Right now I am using jQuery to create the hover highlight effect but is a bit slow. 
I was wondering if there's any way to do it with CSS.

This is what I'm using right now:

```
$('tr').live('hover', function() {
        $('tr[data-group="'+$(this).data('group')+ '"]').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MW69S/

Comment: Is your html correct?  You've not used `data-transport`

Comment: This can be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510753/trhover-not-working

Comment: @Archer. Working demo added. (with an small table)

Comment: `.live` has been deprecated. Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger yeah I know :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: One performance suggestion is to use .on() if you're using a jQuery version over 1.6; and attach the event to the table ID: $('#tableId').on('hover', 'tr', function(){}); With .live() it grabs all of the elements before executing live, also by specifying the tableId and not document(which .live uses) it takes a shorter path.  *Sorry, looks like someone else already suggested*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to highlight other rows natively through CSS based on hovering over one row with that attribute selector.  You would need to involve some sort of javascript in order to do so.

However, I would recommend increasing the performance of your existing jQuery by changing the call to something like this:

```
$('tr[data-group]').on('hover', function() {
  var t = $(this);
  t.siblings('[data-group='+t.attr('data-group')+']').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

That should speed up the whole process, as you're increasing specificity of the selector, thus giving jQuery less to dig through in order to find the elements which you're looking for.

Comment: Needs quotes in the data-group and a single quote before `).toggleClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery performance tip . Is not simple to test its improvement, but looks better. I will apply it.

Answer (score 10):

[Forked a working demo for you](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/c7GYr/). You can achieve this (as long as the rows are always grouped) with multiple `tbody` elements.

```
<table>
    <tbody data-group="666">
        <tr><td>aaaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>bbbbb</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-group="2">
        <tr><td>aaaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-group="XXXX">
        <tr><td>aaaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can then use the altered CSS rule:

```
tbody:hover{
    background:#ff00ff;
}
```

Comment: Clever! I forgot that it was legal to have multiple `tbody` elements in a single table. Might need to test that it works in older browsers, though. The alternative approach is to use [nested tables](http://jsfiddle.net/MW69S/1/), which makes for some rather bulky and ugly HTML.

Comment: It's completely legal, and a great answer if the rows are already grouped.  W3C spec actually expects more than one tbody, as can be found in the DTD: <!ELEMENT table
     (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>

Comment: I prefer not to add more code to the generated HTML table as there can be many rows and I am also applying other jQuery events based on current structure. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JoshBurgess I had to check that it was legal. To be honest, it's semantically ambiguous. Multiple bodies? What does it even represent? But yeah, it works, and it removes the need for scripts. Must remember it for later…

Comment: @Barney Yeah, it definitely adds wrinkles to what you'd expect a table's behavior to be.  Semantically, it's a nightmare.  However, lacking anything like a trgroup element, it's the best currently available.  Great suggestion, completely forgot that multiple tbodies were a thing.

Comment: Tbody is the row equivalent of colgroup that allows you to group related rows together in a semantic way.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Comment: @cimmanon thanks for that. I guess the nested nature of XML makes this necessary. Still, `trgroup` would make more sense. 'body' is usually something of which there is only one.

Comment: Fortunately for us, parsers don't care what the name is, only how it should behave.

Comment: @Steve just noticed your mention of "there can be many rows" — this is another reason not to use jQuery; the performance hit will be bigger since every time a row is hovered, jQuery needs to detect each and every other row element and test to see if it matches the selector. On the other hand, putting hundreds of rows inside a `tbody` wouldn't impact the performance of the code above at all. Just a thought!

Comment: @Steve: then you've just made your own case for revising the other jQuery. Don't change code needlessly, but you should definitely revise for improved performance.

Comment: @DavidThomas what do you mean? It seems to be faster than what I had.

Comment: @Steve it definitely is. Unless you know that the table's not going to change after load (in which case you can cache all the references), it's probably the quickest way of doing this without changing the markup.

Comment: @DavidThomas The biggest problem I see with the introduction of new tbodies into the table is that Steve has already stated that he's got other jQuery functions running on the table.  If any of those rely on the current structure (accessing siblings, traversing to parents, etc.) that change could be potentially sweeping.  I definitely feel that the tbodies answer is more elegant (hell, it's got my upvote), but it may not be perfect for what Steve needs.