# Highlighting pairs of rows, on hover, with css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table where a pair of tr elements make up a visual row

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

If the top row if each pair is hovered over,  the pair of records can be highlighted:

```
/*1st, 3rd, etc and the following tr*/
table.highlightmessagerow tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover,
table.highlightmessagerow tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover + tr,
{
    background-color:#FFFFC0 !important;
}
```

I'm trying to highlight the pair of records when the bottom row of each pair is hovered.  Is this even possible?

```
/*2nd, 4th, etc and the preceeding tr*/
table.highlightmessagerow tbody tr:nth-child(even):hover,
table.highlightmessagerow tbody tr + tr:nth-child(even):hover
{
    background-color:#FFFFC0 !important;
}
```

Comment: You can't actually target a previous sibling with CSS, but you can simulate the behavior with the flex `order` property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. There is no such thing as a previous sibling selector on CSS. 
You should consider just restructuring your HTML and use a much simpler tr:hover.

```css
tr:hover{background:red}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 <br/>
      A
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2 <br/>
      B
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are right, ideally I would restructure the html.  In my case though I want that alignment between cells, which is difficult to achieve without a table and multiple rows.  I did find an alternate post which suggests multiple tbody elements each grouping the rows, and it works great.,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15296496/9266