# Implementing hover color change in CSS class not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my example I have a table with many rows with different color based on Bootstrap classes ("success","warning",...). 
At first if the mouse is over the "success" row it becomes "more green" and it's ok. If a click on "success" row, I replace the "success" class with my class "greenSelected" but if I go over the row, the hover color is gray and not "greenSelected".

I tried with other solutions in the CSS also with !important but id doesn't work.

```
.greenSelected tr:hover{
     background-color:#D0E9C6;
}


.greenSelected:hover{
    background-color:#D0E9C6 !important;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ddxao12/

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510753/trhover-not-working

Comment: You solution http://jsfiddle.net/zzjgwvak/ . @Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a combination of the wrong selector, and insufficient [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Try this instead **[(See JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5ddxao12/1/)**:

```
.table-hover > tbody > .greenSelected:hover td {
  background-color: #D0E9C6;
}
```

---

**Explanation**

Defined within your included Bootstrap CSS is this rule:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td, ... {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

To *override* this rule, your new rule must be *more* specific (in my solution, we're acheiving this by selecting an element by it's class rather than it's tag name). Furthermore, as is pointed out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510753/trhover-not-working), you should set the hover selector at the *table-row* level, but then the elements you wish to change background colour for, are it's *table-cell* children.

Whilst you *could* use the `!important` declaration to overcome the specificity issue, I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, make sure that whenever you create CSS rules, you be only as specific as needs be, and have a good understanding of why your rules are being applied.

Comment: Thanks a million! I think it's better than using !important, right ?

Comment: I'd like to hear a compelling reason why important is *needed* wherever someone tries to use it, so I'd say so

Comment: plus one for mention `CSS specificity`

Answer (score 0):

the background is set on the td so do it like this:

```
tr.greenSelected:hover td{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

Add !important to overwrite bootstraps rules.